# Array inside a static instance of an Object is destroyed

Tags: java, android

I made a class:

```
public class Msg {
     int[] Data;
}
```

In the program startup I create the class and create the array:

```
static Msg rMessage;

rMessage = new Msg();
rMessage.Data = new int[8];
```

The problem is that if I want to use the array later in the program it is destroyed. In the startup I can see the array in the debugger, but later in the code it changes to `null`. The other properties of the class are still set to the right value.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the class to instantiate the array. `Msg.Data = new int[8];` will suffice

Comment: You should use Msg.Data = new int[]... there's no need to instantiate Msg.

Comment: Here you create int array again. here --rMessage.Data = new int[8];

Comment: where do you have the static Msg rMessage? if the answer is: "Inside an Activity" this could be possible. Put it inside a Custom Application Object http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this instead.

```
Msg.Data = new int[8];
```

Comment: I am sorry. By declaring the array as static it works like I want it to. Even though you are right that it should work like this: "Msg.Data = new int[8];" But actually I wantet the array not to be static. I posted the wrong code. Sorry

Comment: @ehmunnehm if you posted the wrong code then edit your post. Otherwise, nobody will be able to answer it correctly.

Comment: Yes I did. Hope you get it now. Sorry

Comment: I think your problem is that you want data[] to be static and not the class. Try setting it to static instead of Msg.

Comment: I want the whole thing to be static not just the data.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by putting this in another non activity class: "static Msg rMessage;"

But it is still a strange behaviour.